# FCKEditor inserting double line break

Tags: javascript, fckeditor, line-breaks

My FCKEditor version 2.6.6 makes double space between lines. I read this change in config should fix:

```
FCKConfig.EnterMode = 'br' ;            // p | div | br 
FCKConfig.ShiftEnterMode = 'p' ;    // p | div | br
```

And well, it makes that the editor inserts br instead of p, but it inserts 2.
It does the same for p and div, it always inserts an additional empty one.
I tried empty values '' but it makes error.

I also found and tried this (although it's for CKeditor, but found similar line in my files):

> Open: fckeditor/editor/js/fckeditorcode_gecko.js Row: 48 Find:

```
I='<br type="_moz">';this._BodyHTML=I; Replace with: I=' ';this._BodyHTML=I;
```

from http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/1150

Doesn't work either.

Note: It happens in Firefox, Chrome, and IE. But in Opera it works well.

Does maybe somebody have experience with this? Thanks in advance!